# Including a wordpress blog as a subfolder

Tags: wordpress, subdirectory

So I have a weird problem here, I have created a website with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript but I have it as a PHP file so I can interact with a Wordpress blog I have also created. I have the WordPress blog in a folder inside my website eg. mywebsite/blog. Now while developing on localhost, everything works pretty fine but when I finally hosted it on a live server, the blog seems to load without the CSS; here's a link to the blog https://www.dexafxacademy.com/blog. At this point, I am lost as this is my first time, including Wordpress as a subfolder, so I don't have an idea of what the problem could be. Note that this works well in my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing a link to your site!

Using the Web Inspector in Chrome, I see that the problem is likely in your WordPress settings.

[image]

- WP is attempting to load all your assets from `https://dexafxacademy/blog`
- The correct URL would be `https://dexafxacademy`**.com**`/blog`

In the WordPress admin of your production site (not local), head to Settings > General and make sure your **WordPress Address** and **Site Address** fields have the correct URL containing `.com`.

Comment: Hello Simmer, thank you for your great help, everything works perfectly now. As I couldn't log in to Wordpress I had to edit the settings from the database. Thank you for helping me out. Thank you so much!